# Polynomial Regression

Tags: statistics, regression

I was doing a regression from some data points I have, and I was considering which kind of regression would give the most accurate model by looking at the R^2 value excel calculated from each type of regression. However, I noticed that when the order of the polynomial is equal to the amount of data points I have, the R^2 value will always be equal to 1. Although this makes mathematical sense, should I avoid using the R^2 value for non-linear regression? In which, case what should I use? (Looking at the fifth polynomial graph, it doesn't look like a good model. How do I determine which one is better then, if not with the R^2?)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: "better" strongly depends on the context, there's no mathematical way to decide what function best fits your data.  As  a rule of thumb, if you know (or suspect) that your data is noisy, don't try to fit a complicated shape (like a high degree polynomial) to it.  That fit is heavily influenced by the noise.

Comment: One indication of overfitting:  as $x$ gets large, your function will go to $-\infty$.  That seems like an impossible conclusion, given that the data is (roughly)  monotonically increasing.

Comment: @lulu Wouldn't it be possible to use a certain equation as a model for a limited domain? For example, if we have a parabola, it might be that only the increasing side of equation represents the data. What I am afraid of is that the linear model will be underfitting the data (for my data, the second polynomial has a bigger R^2).

Comment: Of course adding more parameters gets you a better fit, that would be true for any data.  You can always pass a degree $n$ polynomial through any $n+1$ points. That doesn't make it a more accurate interpolator though.  Look at the gyrations your quintic has to do to fit the points!

Comment: But, again, this isn't a math problem.  If you have reason to believe that your data is  following a quintic polynomial then you should definitely use that model.  But, to the naked eye, the linear fit is much better.

Comment: Many valuable hints you will find in this statistics blog: https://statisticsbyjim.com/?s=R-squared or https://statisticsbyjim.com/?s=Standard+Error

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use something like the $R^2$, consider the adjusted one.

Using you data

- For a linear regression, you will get $0.925431$
- For a quadratic regression, $0.933753$
- For a cubic regression, $0.904233$

So, stop at the quadratic.